# About sylow subgroups in $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, quotient-group

Let $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ and for $p$ prime let $$S(p)= \{ q+\mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z} : \exists k \in \mathbb{N}, k(q+\mathbb{Z}) \} =\mathbb{Z}$$
the $p$- Sylow subgroup in $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ show that:

1.- $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist unique cyclic subgroups $C_{p^k}$ of order $p^k$ in $S(p)$ such that $$C_p \subset C_{p^2} \subset \ldots \subset S(p)$$
2.- $S(p)$ is divisible

for $(2)$ i prove first that $\mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is divisible then in particular for any $q+\mathbb{Z} \in S(p)$ and $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ exists $x+\mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $$k(x+\mathbb{Z})=q+\mathbb{Z}$$
and how $q+\mathbb{Z} \in S(p)$ then exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p^m(q+\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ then these implies that $$p^mk(x+\mathbb{Z})=p^m(q+\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$$
but I'm not quite sure how to conclude that  $x+\mathbb{Z} \in S(p)$.

for (1) i try induction and using the fact that $\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Z}=\oplus S(p)$ but i think to these is not correct.

Any hint or help i will be very grateful

Comment: You don't need the double backslash for the curly brackets anymore. It hasn't been needed for years.

Comment: i know Arturo but i have problems to write $\{$ only i can with $\\{$ maybe a problem of my navigator

Comment: Don't do that, because it messes up the renderer.  I have no idea what your issue is, but to get $\{$ you only type \{

Comment: For 1, consider subgroups of rationals with denominator $p^k$. For 2, every element of $S(p)$ is of order a power of $p$, so it is $k$-divisible whenever $\gcd(p,k)=1$, with a power of itself as a witness.Then prove every element has a $p$th root in $S(p)$.

Comment: thank you very much for the two suggestions Arturo